# How to get the number of count which lies between in range

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

We have one column which has integer values., and I have some ranges as list of tuples[(0,100), (100,200),....].

I have to get how many elements are present in 0 to 100, 100 to 200 in pyspark with or without Window function.

Example:

---

Input:

```
1
10
101
150
200
250
```

Output:

```
{"range": "0-100"      "count": "2"},      {"range": "101- 
200"      "count": "3"},      {"range": "201-300"      "count": "1"},...
```

Comment: show your minimal coding effort

Comment: Please add an example of input and expected output.

Comment: Why do you need to use `pyspark`? Are you working with lots of data?

Comment: Yes @sbottingota

Comment: Each range is for `(1 + end - start)` integer elements (assuming the parentheses represent open interval notation), what's the actual challenge?

Comment: Are these ranges in a pattern of 100s or a collection that could contain any ranges? Can a value be counted in multiple ranges? 0 to 100 then 101 to 200 is a bit strange, they are of different size. 0-99, then 100-199, etc... would be easier.

Comment: it can be any range @tdelaney
it's not only 100, but it can be anything.

Comment: can u please help @tdelaney

Answer (score 1):

Let me know what you think about this:

```
output_df = (
    df
    .withColumn('start_range', (f.col('value') - 1) - ((f.col('value') - 1) % 100) + 1)
    .withColumn('end_range', f.col('start_range') + 99)
    .withColumn('range', f.concat(f.lit('('), f.col('start_range').cast('string'), f.lit(','), f.col('end_range').cast('string'), f.lit(')')))
    .groupBy('range')
    .agg(f.count('*').alias('count'))
)
```

After the reviewing Aman's comments, I think he needs to be able to determine the boundaries of ranges dynamically. The following solution, satisfies this requirement:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1,),
    (10,),
    (101,),
    (150,),
    (201,),
], ['value'])

range_list = [0, 100, 200, 300]

output_df = (
    df
    .withColumn('start_range', f.expr('case ' + ' '.join([f'when value >= {range_list[i]} and value < {range_list[i+1]} then {range_list[i]}' for i in range(len(range_list) - 1)]) + ' else null end'))
    .withColumn('end_range', f.expr('case ' + ' '.join([f'when value >= {range_list[i]} and value < {range_list[i+1]} then {range_list[i+1]}' for i in range(len(range_list) - 1)]) + ' else null end'))
    .withColumn('range', f.concat(f.lit('('), f.col('start_range').cast('string'), f.lit(','), f.col('end_range').cast('string'), f.lit(')')))
    .groupBy('range')
    .agg(f.count('*').alias('count'))
)
```

Comment: if we don't have rang of 100, then how should be logic implemented @SamJ

Comment: can you please explain me logic...

Comment: if we have this type of input [0.9913162,0.99110985,0.99110425,0.9911022,0.9910569,0.99103934,0.9909826,0.9909752,0.9909044,0.9909009,0.9906171,0.9902254,0.9901155,0.9901153,0.9901036,0.9899575,0.98991245,0.98980266,0.9895796,0.98952734,0.9893779,0.9893177,0.98872745,0.9499294,0.9497151,0.93488383]
then how should be the values

Comment: @Aman I have added a new piece to my solution, please check it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have overlapping between the ranges you could also flatten this list of ranges and use the `rdd.histogram` function

```py
input = [0, 20, 30, 40, 150, 170, 210, 250, 280]
ranges = [(0, 100), (100, 200), (200, 300)]
ranges_flattened = list(dict.fromkeys([item for sublist in ranges for item in sublist])) # [0, 100, 200, 300]
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(input)
hist = rdd.histogram(ranges_flattened)[1]
```

Result:

```py
[4, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I tried with this input [0, 20, 30, 40, 100, 200, 210, 250, 300]
and given me [4, 1, 4] output and it's looking good
I am not sure which overlapping u r reffering to.

Comment: I meant if the requested ranges are for example `[(0, 100), (50, 150), (150, 200)]` (the first two overlap) then the output will get you the histogram for bins `(0, 50, 100, 150, 200)`, so you'd need a simple post processing to sum the first 2 numbers to get the count for range `(0, 100)`

Comment: no Islam, I will not get overlap in ranges.

Answer (score 0):

We can Use Bucketizer also..

```
df_final = Bucketizer(
                splits=BINS,
                inputCol="value",
                outputCol="bin_number"
    ).transform(df)
```